# Javascript onclick confirm form submit and flask app

Tags: javascript

I want to add a confirmation to a form action:

```
        <form action="/delete" method="post">
            <button id="deleteForm" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteConfirm(this.form)">Delete</button>
        </form>
```

And in my script.js I wrote the function:

```
function deleteConfirm() {
    
    let text = "Are you sure?\nOk=Delete all data.";
    if (confirm(text) == true) {
        document.getElementById("deleteForm").submit();
    } else {
        alert("Cancelled.");
    }
}
```

But with these codes when I click either ok or cancell, the form will submit. when I click cancel the alert show up but then the action /delete will execute.

Is this an attribute of flask?
Are there another ways to do this?

Comment: you need to add attribute type="button" to your button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add attribute type="button" to your button, and id "deleteForm" add to form

```html
<form id="deleteForm" action="/delete" method="post">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteConfirm(this.form)">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use the onclick event of the button. Instead, attach type="submit" with your buttion. And add the onsubmit attribute with your form. This is the standard way of doing what you mentioned.

```js
function deleteConfirm(myForm) {
    let text = "Are you sure?\nOk=Delete all data.";
    if (confirm(text) == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Cancelled.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="/delete" method="post" onsubmit="return deleteConfirm(this);">
    <button id="deleteForm" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are like many ways to approach this question, but what i would do is that instead of having an entire javascript function just to display a on click  alert i would just wrap it around a input.

```
<input type="submit" value="Delete"
                   onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this data?')">
```

I have used this for like flask data delete and when the user clicks cancel it does not submit the form.

Here is an example of what i just used:
https://jsfiddle.net/12f6bvkq/